# How to solve You don't have permission to access this resource. ubuntu Laravel?

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, apache2

I am working on laravel 8 and i am facing strange issue. Project was working fine 8 hour ago but now i am facing issue You don't have permission to access this resource. my route file is.

```
Route::get('language/{key}', [SwitchLanguageController::class, 'switchLanguage'])->name('language');
Route::get('register', [RegisterController::class, 'showRegistrationForm'])->name('register')->middleware(['otpVerify']);
Auth::routes();
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function (){
Route::get('/404', [\App\Http\Controllers\ErrorController::class, 'notFound'])->name('404');
Route::get('/', [DashboardController::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard');

Route::get('profile/show', [AuthenticationController::class, 'profile'])->name('profile.show');

Route::get('/invoices', [InvoiceController::class, 'index'])->name('invoice');
});
```

when i hit route **http://www.ereciept.com/invoices/** on local server i face this issue.
[image]

Comment: `sudo a2enmod rewrite` then `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: I run it in my root folder of project?

Comment: anywhere in ubuntu

Comment: No change. I have run command for permission after that it happen but i don't know command know

Comment: if i set route like this http://www.ereciept.com/invoices/index its work fine i don't know why

Comment: If you have a dir on `/public/invoices` change the name of `/invoices`

Comment: all route work with two words for example if i set route  ereciept.com/profile then i face error if i set route  ereciept.com/profile/show its work.

Comment: Any Help, #Kmalesh #sta